# Specify order of elements in a SOAP response using java

Tags: java, soap, response

I have a web service that returns a dataset object that contains the current weather forecast along with 0 or more weather alerts for a county/state.  The dataset object just contains a Weather object and an array of Alerts objects.  One of the clients of this would like to have it so the response gives the weather first instead of the alerts.  Is there a way to specify the order of the response elements?  I thought I could just change the WSDL to map out the weather first then the alerts, but that didn't do anything.

Here's the generic WSDL sheet:
(well, it showed formatted in the preview but not after posting... how can I post formatted XML on here?  I tried using back-ticks as well as pre and code).

```
<wsdl:definitions ...>
 <wsdl:types>
  <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ws.sample.com" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <import namespace="http://objects.sample.com"/>
   <element name="getAll">
    <complexType>
     <sequence>
      <element name="county" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="state" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="latitude" type="xsd:double"/>
      <element name="longitude" type="xsd:double"/>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>
   </element>
   <element name="getAllResponse">
    <complexType>
     <sequence>
      <element name="getAllReturn" type="tns1:DataSet"/>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>
   </element>
   <complexType name="ArrayOf_tns1_Alert">
    <sequence>
     <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="item" type="tns1:Alert"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
  </schema>
  <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://objects.sample.com" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <import namespace="http://ws.sample.com"/>
   <complexType name="Alert">
    <sequence>
     <element name="county" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="endDate" nillable="true" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
     <element name="locationCode" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="startDate" nillable="true" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
     <element name="state" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="title" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="warning" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
   <complexType name="Weather">
    <sequence>
     <element name="chancePrecipitation" type="xsd:int"/>
     <element name="period" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="skyConditions" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="temperature" type="xsd:int"/>
     <element name="temperatureType" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="temperatureUnit" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="windDirection" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="windSpeed" type="xsd:int"/>
     <element name="windUnit" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
   <complexType name="DataSet">
    <sequence>
     <element name="weather" nillable="true" type="tns1:Weather"/>
     <element name="alert" nillable="true" type="impl:ArrayOf_tns1_Alert"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
  </schema>
 </wsdl:types>
   <wsdl:message name="getAllResponse">
      <wsdl:part element="impl:getAllResponse" name="parameters"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="getAllRequest">
      <wsdl:part element="impl:getAll" name="parameters"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:portType name="TSTWeather">
      <wsdl:operation name="getAll">
         <wsdl:input message="impl:getAllRequest" name="getAllRequest"/>
         <wsdl:output message="impl:getAllResponse" name="getAllResponse"/>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:portType>
   <wsdl:binding name="TSTWeatherSoapBinding" type="impl:TSTWeather">
      <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
      <wsdl:operation name="getAll">
         <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
         <wsdl:input name="getAllRequest">
            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output name="getAllResponse">
            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:service name="TSTWeatherService">
      <wsdl:port binding="impl:TSTWeatherSoapBinding" name="TSTWeather">
         <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8282/Services/service/TSTWeather"/>
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I don't see how I could specify the order of my service response.

Comment: Paste the WSDL in, highlight the lot and then press Ctrl-K to indent it by 4 spaces.

Comment: You'll need to say something about how you created the service. What toolkit did you use? JAX-WS, or what? What version? Etc.

Comment: I used JAX-WS 2.0 and I used apache axis 1.4 to build the web service.

Comment: Did you build the service from the WSDL, or the WSDL from the service? If the former, then run it through again, so that the definition of the server matches the WSDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases, just changing the WSDL does not change the service, and it's the service that determines the order of the elements in the XML.

Comment: Yea, I realized later that the WSDL is simply the definition for a user to build a client from.  I have been trying to google JAXB and JAX-WS but I do not know what to search for... it appears the elements are just listed alphabetically in most cases.

Comment: I was going to say huh?!? until I realized that you had also written a comment on the OP. I think that comment needs to be rolled into your answer, because a service that doesn't follow its WSDL is a broken service.

Answer (score 1):

We can change the order by adding JAXB annotations in the particular java file.

For example: @XmlType(propOrder = {"x", "y", "z"})